# Android Drawer Layout with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I am using the preset Android Drawer layout. Each selection in the drawer launches a different fragment into the main activity area. My app is used to connect to a SQL server, so I have Username/Password EditTexts and a login button sitting on the app_bar_main for that. How can I make it so that when I hit the login button, it can call a method that is in my fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fragment

```
EditText userName = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.username_id); // id given in your activity layout
EditText password = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.password_id);
Button login = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_id);
userName.getText();
password.getText();
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```